# OnClick Issue, Button Won't set Text?

Tags: android, onclick, textview, mouseclick-event

Hey guys Im just starting to learn code and just when I think I have something working it doesn't seem to work. My problem is that when I click my button the code I set in the OnClick portion should set the text to the number in the variable I created but nothing changes(ie: It stays at 0) and im wondering why. Here is my code for this portion:

```
     private static Button button_win;
private static Button button_loss;
TextView winresult;
TextView lossresult;
double win1,lose1,percent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kotal__khan2);
    button_win = (Button) findViewById(R.id.w2);
    button_loss = (Button) findViewById(R.id.L2);
    win1=0;
    winresult= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Winner);
    lossresult= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Loser);
    lossresult.setText("0");
    winresult.setText("0");
}
public void OnClickButtonListener(){
    button_win.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener (){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    win1= win1+1;
                    winresult.setText(Double.toString(win1));
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Am I missing something? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I knew it was something simple -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call `OnClickButtonListener();` in `onCreate()`.